# Android implicit deeplinking: null extras in Intent

Tags: android, android-intent, android-jetpack, android-navigation, android-deep-link

I want to create an implicit deeplink using the navigation components.

But when I start my app with the following URL:

```
https://my-app.com/cars/ef123-aaf33/parts
```

I get the following error:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{myapp/screens.car.CarActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: 

Activity screens.car.CarActivity@3b8d354 has null extras in Intent { act=android.intent.action.VIEW cat=[android.intent.category.BROWSABLE] dat=https://my-app.com/... flg=0x13008000 cmp=myapp/screens.car.CarActivity }
```

The intent does not have any extras, but it should contain the `carUuid` defined as URL placeholder in the deeplink. The error is thrown as soon as `navArgs()` is evaluated.

This is my setup:

**nav_graph.xml**

```
<fragment
    android:id="@+id/fragment_parts"
    android:name="myapp.screens.parts.PartsFragment"
    android:label="@string/parts"
    tools:layout="@layout/fragment_parts">
    <deepLink
        android:id="@+id/deepLink"
        app:uri="my-app.com/cars/{carUuid}/parts" />
    <argument
        android:name="carUuid"
        app:argType="string" />
</fragment>
```

**AndroidManifest**

```
<activity android:name=".screens.car.CarActivity" >
    <nav-graph android:value="@navigation/nav_graph" />
</activity>
```

**CarActivity**

```
class CarActivity : AppCompatActivity() {


    private val carViewModel: CarViewModel by viewModel { parametersOf(args.carUuid) }

    private val args: CarActivityArgs by navArgs()

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        DataBindingUtil.setContentView<ActivityCarBinding>(this, R.layout.activity_car).also { binding ->
        binding.lifecycleOwner = this
        binding.carViewModel = carViewModel
    }

}
```

Useful links:

[Android documentation for implicit DeepLinks](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-deep-link#implicit)

[On DeepLinks by RayWenderlich](https://www.raywenderlich.com/6014-the-navigation-architecture-component-tutorial-getting-started#toc-anchor-018)

**---- UPDATE ----**

I created a minimal sample project and found hints on what is going on/going wrong. I posted everything on the official issue tracker:
https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/155690730

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got an answer from the Navigation team and a solution/workaround that is good enough for my case. More details including the Sample project can be found here

https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/155690730

**WHY IS THIS HAPPENING (answer from the Google Issue tracker)**

Going to a deep link destination inside of the `SubActivity` is definitely possible, but at the time of `handleDeepLink()` we have not built the `NavDeepLink` object to be able to identify deep link variables. Furthermore, if we were somehow able to parse the URL pattern and place it as the intent extra, for the example you have given, the by `navArgs()` call in `SubActivity` would return a value of "alice", which is meant for the deep link destination, not it's Activity.

The reason `by navArgs()` works in an Activity when you call navigate() with NavDirections is because ActivityNavigator adds the extras to the Intent that is used to start the new Activity. When you use a deep link from adb you bypass all this logic, meaning that the intent starting the activity has no extras, which is why it fails as it should.

There is probably a better approach than nested Activities for whatever your use case my be. That being said, you can make this work by adding an extra with the key name to the adb command used to launch the app from a deep link: --es "name" <"your string">.

**WHAT I DO NOW**

What I do now, since I have full control over the deeplink URLs, is setting the deeplink to SubActivity itself. Furthermore I give the deeplink URL also the information what destination SubActivity should set as startDestination.

This approach works just fine for me. The only drawback is that the MainActivity is also constructed in the backstack, so that the user is first taken back to this MainActivty when pressing the back button. But I can live with that :)

Comment: I don't really understand your final solution. Are you setting the deeplink in Activity in the nav_graph.xml using the new navigation component mechanism or just removing all that and setting the deeplink in the "old way"?

Comment: In short: I am using the navigation components. I send the deeplink to the closest possible Activity and pass enough information to this Activity to make it continue to the desired Fragment.

Comment: Ok, I think I understand now. I also made this work by setting the deeplink in another navigation graph which has a destination to the desired Activity of the final Fragment destination. I was trying to put the deeplink into the destination graph and it doesn't work. It's a solution very far from perfect of the desired behaviour. There should be a warning somewhere in the documentation that deeplinks don't work as expected with multiple activity destinations. There should be an option to pass the destination argument to the Activity Intent.

Comment: I love that "it fails as it should". That's not what the docs say nor what the interface naming suggests. It fails because they didn't know how to implement it better, document it better, name it better, or even Lint it better.

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead in your deepLink:

```
<fragment
    android:id="@+id/fragment_parts"
    android:name="myapp.screens.parts.PartsFragment"
    android:label="@string/parts"
    tools:layout="@layout/fragment_parts">
    <argument
        android:name="carUuid"
        app:argType="string" />
    <deepLink
        android:id="@+id/deepLink"
        app:uri="my-app.com/cars/{carUuid}/parts" >
    </deepLink>
</fragment>
```

Comment: yes, I tried that too, but already as a last resort, because it wouldnt make sense. The delegates are evaluated lazily, so the order shouldnt matter. I just tried it again to be sure: Same error

Comment: Ah yes you are right there! Updated the post on, notice how the argument is placed, can you try that?

Comment: good idea, but also not working, sorry. Lint already warns me that the `argument` tag is not allowed as child of `deepLink`. Tried it anyway: Same error.

Comment: How are you actually delegating the carUuid? Have you debugged that `args.carUuid` from `CarActivityArgs` is not null?

Comment: 1. order of xml definitions: same error 2. I debugged into navArgs() and it is quite simple: intent.extras is always null, so nagArgs() cant even starting its magic. 3. Just trying out the AAC sample [https://github.com/android/architecture-components-samples/tree/master/NavigationBasicSample] and even that is not working properly... 4. I also just found out about the `<argument app:defaultName="carUuid" />` attribute, but also no help. 5. If it is any help: My app has more than 1 Activity, but none of the others are created when using a deep link (which is fine and expected...)

Comment: just found the same error on the google issue tracker: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/155690730
Gonna create a minimal sample and post it there

Comment: have you tried with version 2.2.2 that the issue persists?

Comment: Just for clarification, how are delegating to `args` the string property `carUuid`? Can you update your post with it.

Comment: Thanks for you help btw! I'm not sure what you mean with your last question. I am delegating nothing on my own. According to the navigation documentation, the code I am using is everything neccessary to make this work.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/213508/discussion-between-lucho-and-muetzenflo).